# I am trying to install pycaret module but getting this error everytime

Tags: python

I am trying to install pycaret module on my system but getting this error every time

This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: run `pip` with `-v` (for `verbose`) to see more details. Error may suggests that it has to compile some C/C++ code and it makes problem. Details may explain what makes problem.

Comment: Also provide details about your system (OS and version) and your Python env (Python version, how you installed Python, etc.)